# PHP 5.3.0 NumberFormatter replacement

Tags: php, numberformatter

In PHP 5.3.0+ (on my local server) I have **`intl`** library installed. I use `NumberFormatter` class. I need it to convert floats to various formats (percentage, decimal, currency, etc.)

But on my real server I have PHP 5.2.14 installed. And I can't update it (I'm not the owner).

Do you know (or use) some classes for formatting numbers? Can you recommend something? I need something like `NSNumberFormatter` in iOS, but on PHP.

Comment: the owner of that server needs to be told that PHP 5.2 is end-of-life, and no longer supported.

Comment: Yep, I told him but he doesn't care...

Comment: I mean, I can't update PHP at the moment.

Comment: [Ask your hoster to install from PECL:](http://de.php.net/manual/en/intl.requirements.php) *This extension is bundled with PHP as of PHP version 5.3.0. Alternatively, the PECL version of this extension may be used with all PHP versions greater than 5.2.0 (5.2.4+ recommended).*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using [number_format](http://www.php.net/number_format)? It is fairly limited compared to NumberFormatter, but might be enough for your needs.

Another option that might be more suitable for currency formatting is [money_format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php), but that requires that all the locales are properly configured on the servers.

Yet another option is [Zend_Currency](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.currency.html), which offers very powerful currency formatting in various locales regardless of the server configuration. Zend Framework supports PHP 5.2.x.

Comment: But how can I replace this code with number_format: `$formatter->setAttribute(NumberFormatter::MIN_FRACTION_DIGITS, 0); $formatter->setAttribute(NumberFormatter::MAX_FRACTION_DIGITS, 3);` ?

Comment: Sorry, I think number_format only supports a fixed number of decimal points. Perhaps you could somehow deduce the number of decimal points you want beforehand and call it appropriately.

Comment: But installing the Zend Framework is simply a matter of uploading the PHP files, which you can do yourself, unlike upgrading PHP.

Comment: Solved by using `echo rtrim(rtrim(number_format($num, 3, ',', ''), '0'), ',');`. Thanks for suggestion!